# Create a level terrain similar to Tiny Wings using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I would like to create a textured terrain in SpriteKit similar to the one in the game Tiny Wings.  Using cocos2d, I was able to follow Ray W's tutorial and get the look I wanted...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32954/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-1

Is plotting points to make triangles to fill with a repeating texture (or something similar) possible using SpriteKit?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

yeah you can create a game like tiny wing with sprite kit

1. step create serval CGMutablePath using http://dazchong.com/spritekit/ tool its a online SKPhysicsBody Path Generator and save them in a  NSMutableArray array suppose you have only one level in your game for multiple level create multiple  NSMutableArray array with multiple random saved CGMutablePath items
2. be sure all CGMutablePath have static physics body don't make it dynamic now

   inside your init function add all paths one by one in a order that first path ends start of second path and so on make by this you can make a huge loop of serval path which are connecting with each other.

   don't make more paths because too many physics body makes your game slow
3. now inside update function move all item of your array from right to left be sure 
    when you reach last item of your NSMutableArray array add it again at the begging of your looping algo.

   ```
   -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

   }
   ```
4. make a tiny bird and give it a dynamic physics body

   set collision and contact category of  tiny bird as well as your loop paths
5. now inside didBeginContact function you can get contact between your tiny bird and path .now you can apply a little Impulse  or you can get contact.collisionImpulse between your bird and path apply apply that value to the bird acc to your game

   ```
   -(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
   {
      //contact
      CGPoint contactPoint=CGPointMake(0, 0);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the great physics information dragoneye, I'm sure it'll come in handy.  However, the part I'm asking about is the actual texture of the terrain/hills.  Basically, once I have the points of my terrain, how can I fill those triangles with texture?

Comment: create those triangles in photoshop  any other image editing tool then add them in a texture atlas fetch them one by one and add physics body over those texture using http://dazchong.com/spritekit/

Answer (score 0):

So it seems what I need to use (or at least I had in mind) are vertex shaders, but those are not currently supported in Spritekit.  Right now, only fragment shaders are allowed from what I could find.

I did however see that you can create an SKShapeNode and set its texture property.  The only problem with this is there is no option to "tile" that image throughout the SKShapeNode.

I did find this which seems to solve that issue (although I have not tried it out).
https://gist.github.com/man1/413642637ebd0b00fe2b

Seems like quite a work around!

In the end, I decided to use Cocos2d for this project as it supports both vertex and fragment shaders.  With a bit of trial and error, I got it to work wonderfully.